# Range of the function $f(x)=\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\bigg)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

I need to find the range of the function $$f(x)=\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\bigg)$$

Now, here is my approach:

$$-1 \leq \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leq 1$$

But, I also know that this is always positive, so

$$0 \leq \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leq 1$$

Now, if I took the $\cos^{-1}$ throughout, I would get

$$0\leq f(x) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now I have two questions. Firstly, how do I know that the minimum and max values of $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ is $0$ and $1$? I know that this seems to be increasing, so its value is only limited by the $cos^{-1}$ argument, but how do I know if the minimum value is $0$ or something that is greater than $0$?

The answer in my book says that range of the function is $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ which seems to imply that $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ can not take the value of $1$

An explanation would help greatly

Comment: Find it's domain and then go for it's range. I think it may also be better to analyze $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ using calculus

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ that you are looking at? With the $x^2$ in the numerator, it is not bounded from above. If I am correct, then you can use $\cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2} - \tan ^{ - 1} x$.

Comment: @Gary No, I have stated the correct question. What do you mean it's not bounded from above??

Comment: For large positive $x$, $\frac{{x^2 }}{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }} \approx \frac{{x^2 }}{{\sqrt {x^2 } }} = x$.

Comment: @Gary Yes, but since I have a cosine inverse function, whose domain is $[-1,1]$, it's max possible value should be equal to or less than $1$

Comment: WA says range is not $[0,\pi/2]$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Darccos%28x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E1%2F2%29

Comment: @Mathsmerizing Strange. The graph suggests otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's what I am wondering. It should be $[0,\pi/2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, an even function that is decreasing for $x\lt 0$ and increasing for $x\gt 0$. We see that

$$g’(x) = \frac{x^3+2x}{(x^2+1)^{\frac 32}} =0 \implies x=0$$ Clearly, this corresponds to a minimum. Therefore, $0\le g(x) \le 1$ where the upper bound is a consequence of the restriction by $\cos^{-1}x$. This means $f(x)=\cos^{-1}(g(x))$ can vary from $\cos^{-1} 0$ to $\cos^{-1} 1$. Indeed, your answer is correct. The range is $$\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

Comment: Isn't it also increasing for negative values of x??

Comment: @Techie5879 No. $g’(x) \lt 0$ for $x\lt 0$.

Comment: Yes I see, but the graph of the function seems to suggest that it is greater than 0 for x < 0 also??

Comment: Yes, it is undoubtedly positive. But decreasing.

Comment: sorry, I had mixed up some stuff